# Why my blender layout area appears a mark like hourglass? and how to close it

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, 3d-cursor, viewlayers, tools

I don't know what function I pressed, suddenly, the blender layout area appears a mark that looks like "hourglass"(see the picture below), and it does no effect but just a little bit annoying. I try to close it, but still can't.

If anyone knows how to close it and what function did I press accidentally, please help me to fix it. thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just tap <kbd>W</kbd> again and it disappears.
With <kbd>W</kbd> you just change the selection mode.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  But I tap W change the selection mode still can't select it or let it disappear. It looks like not a object.   : (